# What are my options for packaging my Java Project?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, txt

So I am working on my first program that I'm actually making some money off of. It consists of a .jar, two txt files (user accessible), a few batch files, and some images. Are there any options for packaging these nicely together instead of passing a bunch of loose files in a folder off to my client? I'm a college student, and this hasn't been talked about yet...

Comment: If you explain what your program does and/or how you make money from it, we could provide with better advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use packages and different folders for different class file or extra files as you wish. Try to organize the similar files in a group in a folder. use **lib** folder for keeping your dependencies and **src** folder for keeping all your source codes. Also you can use a java project manager extension in your desired code editor.

For reference here is one of my projects folder structure (I Use VS CODE for coding) -

[image]

Comment: Using Maven or Gradle is universal when dependencies are needed; a manual `lib` directory is both more trouble and less reliable.

Comment: Okay, thank to you for letting me know this. So I guess I should stop using manual lib folders !